# Trying to install Magento, Instead of getting localhost/magento2/setup I get the response "Object not found!"

Tags: php, magento, configuration, xampp, localhost

I've watched 3 different videos on how to install `Magento`.
They all include a step of typing in `localhost/magento2` which then leads to the setup page.
I believe there is something wrong with my xampp configuration, but I'm not sure how to fix it or where to look.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-install-magento-2-on-localhost-via-xampp/

You can go through these steps and you will succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the step by step guide.  However, I'm still running into the same problem:  "object not found"  Is there something a xampp configuration file that needs to be adjusted possible?

Comment: just put localhost in url and see what comes

Comment: It shows me the folder of a project that i've been working on that's located at C:\xampp\htdocs\mystuff\week7\scratchd2-demos

Comment: I got help.  The problem was that we had created a virtual host that kept pointing to the wrong directory.  So we had to alter the httpd-vhosts.conf file located in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra